# Plot for probeid and positions

Tags: r, plot, stat

I need to have a plot such that I should have probe id and positions on x-axis and p-values on y-axis.

```
ProbeId        Position P-values
382062871   39487   0.001
363644817   61749   0.001
363644421   62233   0.001
23567225    77477   0.385320006
23567242    77893   0.005
44733243    85746   0.49538903
31565337    88022   0.001
342504476   88873   0.447279715
34250450    89299   0.005
34250450    89300   0.02
15730557    89601   0.001
157305176   89482   0.001
37405140    89895   0.001
3843741143  90199   0.001
24558746    120285  0.001
106768141   121095  0.001
156111167   121830  0.001
343446115   125693  0.001
34344634    125852  0.001
350444118   126921  0.001
```

Comment: Scatter plot?  `plot(dat$ProbeId, dat[["P-values"]])` - it's not really clearly what you mean by having two variables on the x-axis: two separate plots; different scales above and below chart (if one is a function -ideally linear - of the other); or two plots superimposed upon each other (in which case the different orders of magnitude might pose a visualisation problem)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you can either use the "number" of probes as your x-axis and the p-value as your y axis and label the probes with the probeID : (Let's name your data "data")

```
plot(1:20,data[,"P-values"],xaxt="none",las=1,xlab="Probe ID",ylab="p-value")
axis(1,at=1:20,labels=data[,"ProbeID"])
```

or plot the actual probe location (but this can end up in really "funny" plot due to the space between probes...) and also label the probes with the probeID :

```
plot(data[,"Position"],data[,"P-values"],xaxt="none",las=1,xlab="Probe ID",ylab="p-value")
axis(1,at=data[,"Position"],labels=data[,"ProbeID"])
```

Because the probe IDs are quite large, you may want to rotate the labels, then you'll have to use the function text instead of axis.